# Is there a way to display the latest file of multiple paths with information in a table format?

Tags: powershell, file

I check every day, whether a CSV-File has been exported to a specific folder (path). At the moment there are 14 different paths with 14 different files to check. The files are being stored in the folder and are not deleted. So i have to differ between a lot of files with "lastwritetime". I would like a code to display the results in table format. I would be happy with something like this:

Name LastWriteTime Length

ExportCSV1  21.09.2022 00:50  185

ExportCSV2  21.09.2022 00:51  155

My code looks like this:

```
$Paths = @('Path1', 'Path2', 'Path3', 'Path4', 'Path5', 'Path6', 'Path7', 'Path8', 'Path9', 'Path10', 'Path11', 'Path12', 'Path13', 'Path13')

foreach ($Path in $Paths){
    Get-ChildItem $path | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime}|
select -last 1

Write-host $Path
}

pause
```

This way i want to make sure, that the files are being sent each day.
I get the results that i want, but it is not easy to look at the results individually.
I am new to powershell and would very much appreciate your help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: In your desired output, what is the `Name` column supposed to be? Is it the name of the current folder you are passing to `Get-ChildItem`?

Comment: @zett42 i would like to have the names of all 14 files in the name column, so i can distinguish between the files easily.

Comment: Try `Select -last 1 -Property Name, LastWriteTime, Length`

Comment: This seems to work, however some paths are listed between the filenames for example:  
           Export1.csv Export2.csv \\path2 Export3.csv \\path3                    
I can't get the comment to show my problem in table format, i hope you understand it anyways. How can i fix this problem, to show ony filenames, lastwritetime and length?
thank you in advance.

Comment: Remove `Write-host $Path`

Comment: BTW, if you have more than 3 columns, you have to use `Format-Table`, otherwise you get list format. `Select -last 1 -Property Name, LastWriteTime, Length, AnotherProperty | Format-Table`

Comment: Thank your for your help,, but if i use format table, every file with its properties is displayed individually with 2 rows of space in between, so it is actually harder to read. Can i put the format-table command and still have it displayed like before (one below the other)? /////////////// i also tried to use the pause, start sleep, sleep, ... commands to stop the window from closing after the script has run, but then the script won't even run once. I can get it to work in the taskplaner with the `noexit` command, is there a way to run the script and then pause outside the taskplaner?

Comment: I've added an answer that shows how to put everything in a single table. `Pause` should work in the script. Alternatively `Read-Host`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from my comments, here is how you could do this:

```sh
$Paths = @('Path1', 'Path2', 'Path3', 'Path4', 'Path5', 'Path6', 'Path7', 'Path8', 'Path9', 'Path10', 'Path11', 'Path12', 'Path13', 'Path13')

$Paths | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem $_ | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime} | Select-Object -Last 1
} | Format-Table -Property Name, LastWriteTime, Length
```

If you want to keep using `foreach()` instead, you have to wrap it in a scriptblock `{…}` to be able to chain everything to `Format-Table`:

```sh
. {
    foreach ($Path in $Paths){
        Get-ChildItem $path | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime} | Select-Object -Last 1
    }
} | Format-Table -Property Name, LastWriteTime, Length
```

Here the `.` operator is used to run the scriptblock immediately, without creating a new scope. If you want to create a new scope (e. g. to define temporary variables that exist only within the scriptblock), you could use the call operator `&` instead.

Comment: works perfect for me, thank you.